# Referencing Ninject in class library in ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that uses the Ninject.MVC3 extension to setup DI in my MVC application. Namely, there's the `NinjectMVC3.cs` file in the `App_Start` folder where my bindings are defined. This works well for DI into my application's controllers.

In addition to the ASP.NET MVC web application, my Solution also contains a class library projects, let's call it `MyProject.Core`, which has my domain model, services, and so on. In there I have a class called `UserServices` that uses a service called `EmailServices`, like so:

```
public class UserServices : IUserServices
{        
    private readonly IEmailServices _emailServices = new EmailServices();

    public void CreateUser(...)
    {
        // Create user...

        _emailServices.SendWelcomeEmail(newUser);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `UserServices` class has a hard-coded dependency on `EmailServices`, but I'd like for that to be configured to use DI, as well. Namely, in my ASP.NET MVC application (or unit test project or wherever) I want to be able to say, "Bind `IEmailServices` to use `TestEmailServices`" and have the `UserServices` class use `TestEmailServices` instead of `EmailServices`.

How do I go about doing this? I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
public class UserServices : IUserServices
{        
    private readonly IEmailServices _emailServices = kernel.Get<EmailServices>();

    ...
}
```

But I'm not sure where `kernel` is going to come from, in this case. Is what I'm asking making any sense, or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with constructor injection, like this:

```
private readonly IEmailServices _emailServices;

public UserServices(IEmailServices emailServices)
{
    _emailServices = emailServices;
}
```

The service injection into your controllers should be handled automatically by the Ninject custom controller factory, which'll use the configured IoC container to resolve the `IUserServices` object when the controller is created, which will in turn be given an `IEmailServices` object by the container:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserServices _userServices;

    public MyController(IUserServices userServices)
    {
        _userServices = userServices;
    }
}
```

When you're unit testing, you can manually inject a fake or mock email service into the user service.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. Do not use the Ninject kernel as a service locator. Do not couple your library implementations to Ninject. Just let it construct the entire object tree in the main application.

Comment: Ah, I should have just tried that! <slaps forehead /> :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC 3 anyway, how about registering Ninject with the built-in DependencyResolver?

```
System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(yourKernel);
```

Then, you can just use

```
var svc = System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<bla>();
```

where you need it. I don't know off hand if SetResolver accepts the Ninject Kernel directly or if you need a wrapper class, but I'd consider that the cleanest solution.

Comment: This will work, but it still relies on the Service Locator anti-pattern and is entirely unnecessary in MVC, where you can just register Ninject as the controller factory and use ordinary constructor injection everywhere else. Not to mention, it couples the class library to `System.Web.Mvc`, which doesn't seem right...

Comment: @Aaronaught Yes and no. DependencyResolver in MVC 3 handles everything (so no need for a controller factory anymore, it uses DI automatically if the DependencyResolver can resolve it). However, there may be situations where it's simply not an option to inject all dependencies (e.g., I have an HtmlHelper that uses a Service which handles some formatting things - this CAN be done in the controller and put on the model, but that would be overkill for a service solely for display functions)

Comment: `DependencyResolver` is literally a service locator with a new name. I really can't see any advantage to using it over the kernel itself... it's just another layer of indirection? I'm not convinced that there's a legitimate need for it beyond whatever's in the MVC internals, but I suppose there might be some obscure examples out there.

Comment: @Aaronaught It is indeed just another layer. If you have the Kernel, great. The thing with the DR is that it works regardless of which DI (so if you want to use Unity, AutoFac or whatever it's transparent) and that it gives you a global/static. But yes, it literally is Service Locator. For MVC Internals it replaces the differing mechanisms (e.g., previously there was a controller factory, a view engine, a modelbinder. Now, it will query the DR for everything first)