# How to use SimpleInjector in a multi project solution without creating circular references

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I’m starting a multi project solution that will have more than one entry point, for example a Windows Service, ASP.NET web sites, WebApi Controllers etc. I’ve settled on SimpleInjector as it’s very fast and I do not need any advanced features.

My understanding is that SimpleInjector should be centrally configured on start-up. Starting with the following basic example set of projects

- NS.Controllers
- NS.Core.Data
- NS.Core.Data.Model
- NS.Web
- NS.WindowsService (assume this will not always be running)

With multiple entry points where should the bootstrapping of SimpleInjector go and can/should it be handled centrally (in which case the configuration process would need to reference all projects to be able to set up all solution classes)?

Should I have a global instance (such as NS.Global.Container) that references none of the other projects and each entry point is responsible for adding its own instance requirements on startup (gracefully handling duplicate registrations such as NS.Core.Model)?

Should I be looking to use the ResolveUnregisteredType event to handle registrations on request?

Am I simply lacking some schoolboy knowledge?

UPDATED:

Links provided by Steven in the comments below give thorough answers to this question.

[Where to locate Ninject modules in a multi-tier application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985452/where-to-locate-ninject-modules-in-a-multi-tier-application/11993030#11993030)

[How to initialize Ninject in a class project part of an mvc site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327940/how-to-initialize-ninject-in-a-class-project-part-of-an-mvc-site/13331282#13331282)

Comment: You could bootstrap the container centrally but I personally would not. Better for each entry point to configure its own container. That's not to say that elements like your repositories wouldn't be done in a single place. Using something like a Windsor installer can be handy for that. The chances of all of your entry points using exactly the same items registered in the container seems unlikely and even if they are now they may not be in the future.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985452/where-to-locate-ninject-modules-in-a-multi-tier-application/11993030#11993030

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327940/how-to-initialize-ninject-in-a-class-project-part-of-an-mvc-site/13331282#13331282

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each entry point should have its own bootstrapping container.

NS.Web should have one, since that is a website (I'm assuming here).
NS.WindowsService should have one, since that is .exe (service).

The other projects look like class libraries, so they would not have a bootstrapping container.

In theory, yes, you can define a partial bootstrapping container in each class library which you can then use in the main bootstrapping container (in the web/service projects), to make life easier. In the partial container you would then do the bootstrapping for the components of that class library.

Comment: [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) is a term which is commonly used to refer to where the bootstrapping container should go.

Answer (score 8):

Why not using `IPackage` interface? You can make packages in each module and then in each entry point just call `container.RegisterPackages();`. For example, all configuration for `NS.Core.Data` will be located in `NS.Core.Data.dll` and so on. Then, it will be useable in both `NS.Web` and `NS.WindowsService`. In `NS.Web` just configure types that are specified to it and then call `container.RegisterPackages();` and so on. Your `NS.Core.Data` package may looks like this:

```
public class CoreDataPackage : IPackage {
    public void RegisterServices(Container container) {
        container.Register<ISomeService,SomeImplementation>();
        // etc...
    }
}
```